# Cannot subscript a value of type '[Int]' with an index of type '()'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

i try

```
  func PRGA() {
    var l = 256
    var i = 0, j = 0, index = 0
    while(l > 0) {
        i = (i + 1) % 256
        j = (j + stable[i]) % 256
        let tmp = stable[i]
        stable[i] = stable[j]
        stable[j] = tmp
        let t  = (stable[j] + stable[i]) % 256
        sonkey[index+=1] = stable[t]
        l -= 1
    }

}
```

this can work in swift2.3,but when i update to swift3,can't work,in sonkey[index+=1] index can't convert to index of type'()'

Comment: That code is pretty unclear, you should probably give the variables more meaningful names. Also, you should use `swap` instead of manually doing a 3 line swap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that `+=` is a statement, not an expression in Swift. It doesn't evaluate to an `Int` value that you can use as a subscript.

However, you don't even need to use `+=` to manually increment `index`, because you can much more easily write this code with a `for` loop:

```
func PRGA() {   
    var i = 0, j = 0
    for index in 0..<256 {
        i = (i + 1) % 256
        j = (j + stable[i]) % 256

        swap(&stable[i], &stable[j])

        let t  = (stable[j] + stable[i]) % 256
        sonkey[index] = stable[t]
    }
}
```

I would be better able to help you if I knew what this code was trying to achieve.

Comment: If you use a for loop with index then you should not have index += 1 inside the loop body

Answer (score 1):

The expression `sonkey[index+=1]` is not valid. Swift 3 removed expressions like `index++`. I'm not even sure what `sonkey[index+=1]` meant in Swift 2.

If your goal is to use the current value of index as a subscript to `sonkey` and then increment afterwords, you now have to do that in 2 steps:

```
    sonkey[index+=1] = stable[t]
    index += 1
```